# not all code path returns a value on Active Directory check

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, session-variables, session-cookies

I am in the process of converting code from VB to C# from an old system that used a base classes for web forms to inherit classes from. My hope is to build a new login for our new extranet that functions like the old system, I may have missed a step but here is the block I tried to convert.

```
public bool CheckAD()
    {
        string fncADStatus = "Failure";
        string fncSuccess = "Success";
        string fncFailure = "Failure";
        fncADStatus = Convert.ToString(Session["SessionADStatus"]);
        try
        {
            if (fncADStatus == fncSuccess)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if (fncADStatus == fncFailure)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (Session["SessionADStatus"] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I get the following error "not all code path return a value" but I don't quite understand why.

Comment: In your catch, you need a return outside of the ifs, or you need an else with a return.  Or you could put a return outside the catch and after it.  Your method must return something since it's not void, and Visual Studio won't let it compile if all code paths don't end in a return.

Comment: What if `fncADStatus != fncSuccess`?  If the if block inside the try evaluates to false, then nothing will be returned by the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it give you the error because you have not mentioned the else statment; nothing will be returned if condition fall in else. do the following will not give you the errro.

```
public bool CheckAD()    { 
        string fncADStatus = "Failure";
        string fncSuccess = "Success";
        string fncFailure = "Failure";
        fncADStatus = Convert.ToString(Session["SessionADStatus"]);
        try
        {
            Boolean output = false;
            if (fncADStatus == fncSuccess)
            {
                output = true;
            }
            return output;
        }
        catch
        {
            Boolean output = true;
            if (fncADStatus == fncFailure)
            {
                output = false;
            }
            if (Session["SessionADStatus"] == null)
            {
                output = false;
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all the code paths in the `catch` block return a result. Usually, you would write something like this

```
public bool CheckAD()
{   
    try {...}
    catch
    {
        if (fncADStatus == fncFailure)
        {
            logger.Debug("One");
        }
        if (Session["SessionADStatus"] == null)
        {
            logger.Debug("Two");
        }

        return false; // <<<<< This bit is missing in your case
    }
}
```